# Google Calendar API (Java) - Invalid time format when creating Google Calendar Event

Tags: java, google-calendar-api

I'm using Java Google API client and I'm trying to create a Google Calendar Event.My authentication and calendar service initialization works (I'm able to log in and fetch my calendars events). The problem occurs when creating the event. Here is my code:

```
    Event event = new Event();

    event.setSummary( title );

    event.setStart( new EventDateTime().setDate( new DateTime( new Date() ) ) );
    event.setEnd( new EventDateTime().setDate( new DateTime( new Date() ) ) );

    return _calendarService.events().insert( GOOGLE_CALENDAR_ID, event ).execute();
```

Here is the error I get:

> com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request { "code" : 400, "errors" : [ { "domain" : "global", "message" : "Invalid value for: \"T\" found, can only parse bare date string: 2014-10-10T15:58:06.165+03:00", "reason" : "invalid" } ], "message" : "Invalid value for: \"T\" found, can only parse bare date string: 2014-10-10T15:58:06.165+03:00" }

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that you are doing `setDate()` and passing in a dateTime (which then results in the "T15:58:06.165" appended to your date). You can either do `EventDateTime().setDateTime()` if you want a timed event or if not, you can do something like:

`new EventDateTime().setDate(new DateTime(true, new Date(), 0));`

Comment: Hi Luc, I am having a problem setting event datetime, can you please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31879644/java-google-calendar-setting-datetime-for-event-giving-400

Answer (score 0):

As [documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/calendar/model/EventDateTime.html#setDateTime(com.google.api.client.util.DateTime)) says, you need to pass timezone to`DateTime` object if it is not set on `EventDateTime` object(and in your case it is not set) using `setTimeZone` method.

So either create new `DateTime` object including timezone, or create new `EventDateTime` object and set its timezone before sending request to server.